# How to use "es" in Spanish as a translation for "it's"

Tags: gramática

I am studying Spanish with the Michel Thomas Method.

As I understand it, `es` means `it's`

Here are some sentences:

> 1. No vale mucho – It’s not worth much
> 2. No, no vale la pena – No, it’s not worth it
> 3. No es lo mismo – It’s not the same
> 4. Es todo lo que necesito – It's all I need

Why do some sentences use `es` for `it's` and other omit `es` altogether.
How do I know when to use `es`?

Comment: FWIW, "es" translates in most cases as "it's" but *es doesn't mean it's*. "Es" is an inflected form of the verb "ser", and would literally translate as "is". In Spanish, the subject can (and generally is) dropped, so "it's" becomes just "is". Besides that, "valer" means "to be worth", so the "es" part is already included in the meaning of the verb. Adding "es" would be just as nonsensical as English "to be be worth" or something like that. But as Ustanak said, in some cases (like this one) it doesn't make much sense to translate things literally because that's just not how languages work.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to make your question title more specific. You can roll it back if you disagree.

Comment: @Yay, So as a rough rule of thumb (which may not always be correct) if the verb implies a subject (like `vale`), you would normally drop the `es`?

Comment: Nope. All conjugated verbs imply a subject; that's why we generally drop the pronoun. A verb itself cannot be dropped, except for some expressions like ¡Quieto! (stand still!). But my point was that here you aren't dropping the "es" because you didn't need it to start with. "Valer" is a verb with no one-word equivalent in English. "To be worth" translates to "valer", so "*it* **is worth** X" translates to "*ello* **vale** X", where *ello* is dropped. It follows that "it **is** not **worth** it" = "[ello] no **vale** la pena", where "la pena" is idiomatic and *ello* is virtually always dropped.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @yay you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's also about the context:

```
It's all I need => **It** is all I need => **Esto/eso** es todo lo que necesito

Is all I need => Es todo lo que necesito
```

In Spanish you can omit the Subject or the **Objeto directo** if the context makes clear what you're talking about.

In the case of the Subject this is called "Sujeto Eliptico" meaning the subject can be derived from the context:

```
He's coming tomorrow => Él viene mañana => Viene Mañana.

Those flowers are beautiful => Esas flores son bonitas => Son bonitas (when you talking about las flores)
```

Comment: FYI, this is a feature of languages like spanish which lead them to be classified as "[pro-drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language)" languages.

Answer (score 1):

Because some constructions in English can't be literally translated into Spanish. (Also converse.)
The classic *it's not worth it = no vale la pena* is not translated with the *es*.

Some other expressions can also be translated with or without the *es*, like *it's true = es cierto* or just *cierto.*

Mostly, you'll learn how to remove the *es* as a part of phrases.

Comment: however "it's not worth it" can be translated as "esto/eso no vale la pena". You can omit the subject or not depending on what you want to make emphasis on.

Answer (score 1):

All languages have different ways to express things, influenced especially by people culture, so you cannot translate literally from one language to another. You need to add cultural variable.

For example, "It’s not worth much" may be literally translated as "No es mucho valer". This could be understood, however, correct translation should be "No vale la pena".

Other classic example that comes to my mind is:

"The more you read, the better your vocabulary becomes". Literally, "lo más que tú lees, lo mejor tu vocabulario es". That does not have any sense in Spanish. For that English construction, the correct translation would be: "Mientras más leas, mejor será tu vocabulario".

Answer (score 1):

*Why do some sentences use es for it's and other omit es altogether. How do I know when to use es?*

Because the meaning is different. The meaning of "es" is "is", not "it's"

No es lo mismo = (eso/esto/aquello, etc) no es lo mismo = It is not the same. This is not the same. That is not the same.

Note the meaning of "is" in this case.

But in: No vale mucho = It has not much value.

There is not "is" in the strict meaning. The expression "it’s not worth much" is a common way to say that someting has not much value, what is the way of saying it in spanish.

Comment: But *It/That/This is not the same* aren't equivalent.